# Joinning columns from different files

Tags: r, bash, awk

I have 48 files in which I have

r1

```
Organ-specific cancer signature Contribution
Esophagus_A 2948.114
Esophagus_B 815.6483
Esophagus_C 1278.381
Esophagus_D 883.5358
Esophagus_E 1446.103
Esophagus_F 880.0416
Esophagus_G 1262.907
Esophagus_H 743.2682
```

r2
..
r15

and

Non_res1

```
Organ-specific cancer signature Contribution
Esophagus_A 2660.722
Esophagus_B 1471.017
Esophagus_C 1639.904
Esophagus_D 0
Esophagus_E 2580.775
Esophagus_F 946.3675
Esophagus_G 2013.654
Esophagus_H 0
```

...

Non_res33

I want a unified file in column one is Organ-specific cancer and 48 more columns are the second column of each separate file

How I can do that?

Comment: Angel! Why do you never provide example output? People ask for this in every single of your plenty of threads be it here on SE, Biostars or elsewhere. This is plain disrespectful. You seem to simply want people to do your work without investing yourself. What have you tried, why doesn't it work? You asked these kinds of simple data rearrangement questions so many times before, do you ever invest time to really understand the solutions users provide? If so you could easily find a solution yourself!

Comment: I don't want to insult any one honestly. In this question I am mentioning in output I have the common first column as the first column and second columns from each file :(

Answer (score 1):

If the first column is always the same:

- [R cbind in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33073145/680068)
- bash `paste file*.txt`

If the first columns in not same:

- [R merge in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8091303/680068)
- [bash Merge multiple files by common field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13710876/680068)